# How to Auto play and Auto Pause Videos using mediaelementjs in Slick Slider

Tags: jquery

My below code is only working on if I have single video in my slider , But I have multiple videos in my slider.

My Slick Slider js :

```
$('.video_full').slick({ 
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.videos',
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000 
});

$('.videos').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.video_full',
    dots: false,
    centerMode: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    vertical: false,
    arrows: false
});

$('.video_full').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    if (currentSlide == 1) {
        $('.video_full').slick('slickPause');
        $('#theVideo').get(0).play();
    }
});

document.getElementById('theVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);

function myHandler(e) {
    $('.video_full').slick('slickPlay');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use J player. From there you can customize the buttons.